# Error shows when I have the correct set up. "SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73"

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, npm, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was doing an automate testing with selenium-webdriver. I am building a driver using chromedriver. It was working good but one day I run a test and this following error message shows up

> SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

but I have no idea what is going on that my package.json shows me it is chromedriver^73.0.0.0. An I have try to uninstall the previous version v2.45, and this similar message shows up.

I have tried so many times for doing npm uninstall and install, also try to install locally but does not help. I know update to v74 works, but some for some reason, i need to stay with the version v73.

Does anyone how to solve this?

Comment: What's your chrome browser version? If  it's 74 then you might have to down grade to 73 as your driver support till version 73.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an mismatch between your chrome browser and driver. Downgrade your chrome browser, please.

Comment: Or upgrade Chrome driver version to 74